# Conditional formatting for a row that contains any information

Tags: 2013, javascript, formatting, conditional

I have a list that I am using for a library check out. When a person populates the check out date field I want my row to be grayed out. The condition would be if a field contains "any" information. This will be a date field that will change when a person checks out book so it wont be static information. Do anyone know how to do this? Here is my script for doing this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var statusColors =  { 
          "" : '#98FB98',
          "12/10/2019" : '#D3D3D3' 
       };

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var status = rows[i]["Check_x0020_Out_x0020_Date"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
       }
     }
   }); 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var status = rows[i]["Check_x0020_Out_x0020_Date"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          if (status)
          {
            row.style.backgroundColor = '#D3D3D3';
          }
          else
          {
            row.style.backgroundColor = '#98FB98';
          }          
       }
     }
   }); 
});
</script>
```